# Put factory method in abstract parent class

Tags: java, spring-boot, design-patterns

There are three different types of **Shape**s: 
**Rectangle**, **Circle**, **Triangle**

These shapes share some code which is placed in the parent (Shape), and there is one method that is implemented differently across these three shapes: **draw()**

Based on the input value, one of the three implementations of that method gets called:

```
abstract class Shape {
    @Autowired
    private Rectangle rectangle;
    @Autowired
    private Circle circle;
    @Autowired
    private Triangle triangle;

    public String drawIt(ShapeEnum shape, String param1, String param2) {
        switch(shape) {
            case ShapeEnum.Rectangle:
                return rectangle.draw();
            case ShapeEnum.Circle:
                return circle.draw();
            case ShapeEnum.Triangle:
                return triangle.draw();
        }
    }
    protected int sharedMethod1() {//....}
    protected int sharedMethod2() { //...}
    protected abstract String draw();
}

@Controller
public class Controller {
    @Autowired
    private Shape shape;

    @RequestMapping(path = "", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
    public String getDrawing(@RequestBody GetShapeRequest shapeRequest) {
        return shape.drawIt(ShapeEnum.valueOf(shapeRequest), shapeRequest.getParam1(), shapeRequest.getParam2());
    }
}
```

Obviously this doesn't work, because Spring cannot instantiate an abstract class that has three implementations.

I'm wondering if there's a design pattern to have parent at the top to decide which child to call. I don't like the idea of wiring in all concrete classes into the controller because I want the parent class to control the flow rather than the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Qualifier` annotation to specify which `implementation` needs to be used.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("childShape")
private Shape shape;
```

Comment: But what about the next request that comes in? If I bind Shape to Rectangle, what if the next request is for Circle?

Comment: In that case, I believe no other ways other than instantiating multiple implementations of your class separately.